# Running Alert Dialog While Asynctask is processing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I currently have an android application that runs an asynctask when a button on the activity is clicked. While the asynctask is busy processing its task, I want the activity to display an alertdialog (loading...) to let my users know that the app is busy processing the request, and not just frozen or crashed. Currently, I have the code written like this:

LoadingDialogue.java

```
public class LoadingDialogue {

private Activity activity;
private AlertDialog dialog;

public LoadingDialogue(Activity myActivity){
    activity = myActivity;
}

public void startLoadingDialogue(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_dialogue,null));
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}

public void dismissDialog(){
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

and this is how I implemented it in my activity:

```
CustomAsyncTask asyncTask = new CustomAsyncTask();
loadingDialogue.startLoadingDialogue();
String responseString = asynctask.execute().get()
loadingDialogue.dismissDialog();
```

However, my loading dialog does not show! It works if I just do it without the async task though.

Thanks!

Comment: Dont use the .get() call on your asyctask. It blocks all. Handle the result in inPostExecute. Use a normal progressbar instead of your alert.

Answer (score 2):

That code is broken in so many ways.

1. Never use `AsyncTask.execute().get()`. Doing that gets the result immediately, which turns it from asynchronous to synchronous. Basically at that point there's no reason to make it an async task, just do it in the body. If your response is that you need the result immediately, you don't understand asynchronous programming.  Put any code that needs the result in the `onPostExecute`.

   Really forget that `get()` exists at all.  There's one or two cases where it can be useful, but 99% of the time using it is an error.
2. The android UI only refreshed when the main thread returns to the looper. So doing show dialog, then doing `get()`, then doing hide it won't work-  it won't show until the entire block is done and control is returned to the looper, by which time its hidden again.

   Instead, use `dialog.show()` in `onPreExecute` and hide in `onPostExecute`. That will make it work.
3. It's kind of odd to have a class holding a dialog like that. It's more normal to derive a class from AlertDialog and just show/hide it. Although this isn't necessarily wrong, there's cases where this may be more convenient.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am quite new to android programming, and I can see how .get() would destroy the purpose of asynctasks. Ill try using the onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods. Just wondering... Could I pass the activity onto the async tasks, and allow the asynctasks to control when the loading alertdialog is displayed or hidden, or would I have to add a listener onto the activity class to have this done?

Comment: You can pass an Activity like any other parameter.  There's only a few things to worry about with that.  First, never store an Activity in a static variable.  Second, never pass it to another Activity or Service which stores it.  Third, do not pass it to a Thread or AsyncTask with a long or unbounded lifetime.  The reason for this is that if you do, the memory of the entire Activity is leaked, which includes all of the high memory graphic components.  Threads or tasks with a lifetime in seconds are ok, as it will delay but not prevent garbage collection.